# Trying to get head and tail in the same line in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R and am trying to get both the head and the tail in one line. (Sorry if I'm not using the right terminology)

This is what I have so far:

```
x3 <- c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90)
testFL4 <- function(x) {
    rbind(head(x, 2), 
          tail(x, 2))
}
testFL4(x3)
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]   10   20
[2,]   80   90`
```

I want to have the end result to be

```
testFL4(x3)
#> [1] 10 20 80 90
```

I feel like I'm missing something simple here

Comment: Something like `c(head(x3, 2), tail(x3, 2))` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `c()` instead of `rbind()`:

```
c(head(x, 2), tail(x, 2))
```

Comment: ohhh my godd I'm such an idiot sometimes. Thanks so much everyone!